# services.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found services.sh: line 74: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: php, linux, laravel, bash, shell

I never use bash file in laravel before.
I found a github project and I downloaded and try to run it.
I try to run this file in background.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $1 = "daemon" ]; then
    echo "daemon"
    while sleep 1
    do
    PID=$(ps aux | grep 'daemon:ticker' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ -z $PID ]]; then
        php artisan daemon:ticker &>/dev/null &
    fi

    PID=$(ps aux | grep 'daemon:signals' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ -z $PID ]]; then
        php artisan daemon:signals &>/dev/null &
    fi

    PID=$(ps aux | grep 'daemon:orders' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ -z $PID ]]; then
        php artisan daemon:orders &>/dev/null &
    fi

#    PID=$(ps aux | grep 'ssh -D 1337' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
#    if [[ -z $PID ]]; then
#        ssh -D 1337 -f -C -q -N root@149.28.135.20
#    fi

    done

fi

if [ $1 = "status" ]; then
    echo "status ..."
    PID=$(ps aux | grep 'daemon:ticker' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ -z $PID ]]; then
        echo "ticker Daemon Stopped"
        else
        echo "ticker Daemon Running"
    fi

    PID=$(ps aux | grep 'daemon:signals' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ -z $PID ]]; then
        echo "Signals Daemon Stopped"
        else
        echo "Signals Daemon Running"
    fi

    PID=$(ps aux | grep 'daemon:orders' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ -z $PID ]]; then
        echo "Orders Daemon Stopped"
        else
        echo "Orders Daemon Running"
    fi

    PID=$(ps aux | grep 'ssh -D 1337' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ -z $PID ]]; then
        echo "Tunnel Daemon Stopped"
        else
        echo "Tunnel Daemon Running"
    fi

fi

if [ $1 = "restart" ]; then
    pkill -f "php artisan daemon:"
    echo "restarted"
fi

if [ $1 = "stop" ]; then
    pkill -f "php artisan daemon:"
    pkill -f "services.sh"
    echo "stopped"
fi
```

by this command

```
sh services.sh
```

error is

```
services.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found services.sh: line 74: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I run this bash file in window.
how can solve this error.
can someone explain me how use .sh file in laravel project.
I want to understand basic concept also.

Comment: `\r` is a Windows line ending, which linux apparently doesn't like in its bash file. Re-edit the file in Linux.

Comment: Use `dos2unix` to get rid of the carriage return. Next time be careful how you configure your text editor before you create a file: Nearly all editors can be instructed to use a linefeed as a line terminator.

Comment: Elham_Jahani has a point. You're running `sh services.sh`, but not passing any arguments in. The script doesn't have a case for a missing argument

Comment: I am newbie in this .sh file , so how can fix it?

Comment: @leon You first need to format the script. Run this: `dos2unix services.sh`.  You also need to pass an argument to the script like: `services.sh daemon`. You have 4 available arguments that you can use: `daemon`, `status`, `restart` and `stop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have $1 in your script but when you run script you do not have any input to your script

Comment: how can fix it?

Comment: sh services.sh stop